Would this question be ok?
I'm trying to track down a list of "important" science fictions works that I got off the Internet back in mid-late 80s.  I remember some details about the list and am hoping that maybe someone else will have heard of it or be able to suggest different ways of searching for it than what I've tried.
Asked, and someone found it!

Did you ask on Codidact?

If you're searching for a specific list, than that would probably count as a question with a single correct answer, about a work related to the genre.  Technically it would be an on-topic and acceptable question to ask.
My concern is if it's not actually a fixed, published list.  From what you say it sounds like a Usenet post; if it's just someone's personal post, it may be archived somewhere in its original form, but it may also have been modified or rewritten numerous times by other people.  In that case, this may turn into a case where there are a bunch of possible answers and no way to determine which one is "right."
On the balance, I would say that if you have a good-faith belief that it's a single list, say attributable to a recognized figure in the community, then it's probably okay to ask.  (I can't guarantee you won't get any downvotes for it though.)

I am looking for a specific list and I think I can limit it enough to have one "correct" answer.
